# scriptEditor <javascript> how to wrap "data" in hyperlink before passing into cell of Numbers to be clicked on

Tags: applescript

Im using ScriptEditor to write an automate a task using Javascript instead of appleScript, and Im unable to HYPERLINK my data before passing it as a value to the cell...

ive tried "" and that was rejected by script Editor.

```
tableName.cells["B" + 3].value = <a href=dataList[0]> 12</a>;
```

Comment: What data?  What cell?  Please edit your question to include some (any) details about your script so people can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

'=HYPERLINK("http://www.yahoo.com", "yahoo.com")'